Usage of RAP Side Effects for field added by virtual element
I have added a field ZTEST using virtual element in C_SalesOrderManage view.
Calculation of this field is dependent on 2 fields from another view C_SalesOrderItemManage.
Can this be achieved using RAP Side Effects??
Or there can be another way to achieve this??
I have added a field ZTEST using virtual element in C_SalesOrderManage view.
Calculation of this field is dependent on 2 fields from another view C_SalesOrderItemManage.
Can there be a way to achieve this??
